# Propel toArray Mechanics in Doctrine?

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I was using Propel for a long time and now I want to try Doctrine.
In My Propel days I used `PropelObjectCollection::toArray` (for a collection) or `PropelObject::toArray()` for a single record to convert the `PropelObject` via array to json.

In my company we override the toArray method to store virtual columns in the array and then the json string.
For example:

```
public function toArray() {
  $arr = parent::toArray();
  $arr['full_name'] = $this->getFullName(); // full_name isnt part of the table, it's just a getter
  return $arr;
}
```

When I turn this into json i have my full_name property in my json and then in my Extjs store Object (we use extjs).

Now I wanna try doctrine, but doctrine doesn't seem to allow this. 
Can i override a function or property in my doctrine class, or can I do this by annotations, is it possible to generate a json with propertys `('first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name')` if my Doctrine class only has the properties $first_name, $last_name and no $full_name 
or is there a work around to achieve the same?

Thanks for your help

Edit:
I found something in JMSSerializerBundle if you use Annotations:

[@VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations)

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
```

at the top of my Doctrine Entity File and an example method

```
/**
 *
 * @VirtualProperty
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullName() {
    return $this->getName(). " mylastname";
}
```

my json then contains the virtual property full_name

Comment: Welcome on SO. Try to use only the tags that are relevant to *your current question*. Just because you're using ExtJS doesn't mean that this question about Doctrine should be tagged with extjs.

Comment: Thanks, have clicked all the tags, sry